# How to convert groupby multi-index as a new columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I have a DataFrame like below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df["user_id"] = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4]
>>> df["cate"] = ["a","b","c","b","c","a","a","b","c","d"]
>>> df["prob"] = [np.random.rand() for _ in range(len(df["user_id"]))]
```

[image]

I want to convert the `pro` of each `cate` as a new columns of the user(`user_id`),like this:

[image]

The only solution to solve this problem is using `for loop`,when I have tens of thousands users, it's very very slowly!

```
user_ids = list(set(df["user_id"]))
cates = list(set(df["cate"]))

user_probs = pd.DataFrame()
for uid in user_ids:
    d = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [uid]})
    for c in cates:
        ratio = df[(df["user_id"] == uid) & (df["cate"] == c)]["prob"]
        ratio = 0 if len(ratio)==0 else float(ratio)
        d["cate_"+c+"_prob"] = ratio

    user_probs = pd.concat([user_probs, d])
```

So, Does Pandas have built-in method to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot would work perfectly well here

```
df.pivot('user_id', 'cate', 'prob').reset_index().fillna(0)
```

You get

```
cate    user_id a           b           c           d
0       1       0.853583    0.161935    0.388652    0.000000
1       2       0.000000    0.554185    0.177939    0.000000
2       3       0.700654    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
3       4       0.781307    0.634584    0.861808    0.130701
```

Another way using set_index

```
df.set_index(['user_id', 'cate']).prob.unstack(fill_value = 0).reset_index()
```

You get the same result

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!